# Windows 8 email account setupwith Verizon.net

Tags: windows-8, email, user-accounts

I know that  have the correct information but Windows 8 says it cannot find settings for my account.  Incoming Server seems to be hard coded for IMAP and Verizon is POP3.  What do I do so set up my verizon email?

Comment: Windows 8 mail app does not support POP for technical reasons (POP does not sync with server).

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround right now is to setup Gmail as a bridge but unfortunately it's for incoming only.

http://www.howtogeek.com/130516/how-to-access-pop3-email-accounts-in-windows-8/